# passing multiple strings to get path but no results in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have the following codes:

```
filter MultiSelect-String( [string[]]$Patterns ) {

    # Check the current item against all patterns.
    foreach($Pattern in $Patterns) {

        # If one of the patterns does not match, skip the item.
        $matched = @($_ | Select-String -Pattern $Pattern)

        if(-not $matched) {
            return
        }
    }

    # If all patterns matched, pass the item through.
    $_
}

Get-ChildItem -recurse | MultiSelect-String 'v1','Produit','quota'| select -unique path
```

when i execute the code it should give me the path + the name of the file (directory/filename)

However it gives me no results, but when I executed the same without  |select -unique path

it gives me results for which it is useless for me. How to get the directory path and the file name. Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Path` is not a properties for `fileInfo object`. Use `directory` or `fullname` instead:

```
Get-ChildItem -recurse | MultiSelect-String 'v1','Produit','quota'| select -unique directory # for path or fullname for path\filenamt.ext
```